# How to use a Map instead of Class object to represent data in Scala

Tags: list, scala, class, dictionary

My goal is to use a `Map` (immutable) instead of class to represent my data in Scala. I'm simply transforming the data from one source file into another format and using a `Map` seems reasonable rather modeling a class to represent my data.

Example:

I have a list of lists for my raw data.

```
val x = List(List("a","b","c"), List("x","y","z")) // the values, order matters
val y = List("field1","field2","field3") // the keys, order matters
```

I want to apply the schema to the raw data and create a List of Maps. Order wont matter with Map.

```
val z = List(Map("field1" -> "a", "field2" -> "b", "field3" -> "c"), List("field1" -> "x", "field2" -> "y", "field3" -> "z"))
```

I have tried zip but thats not what i want

```
val z = x zip(y) toMap
  z: scala.collection.immutable.Map[List[String],String] = Map(List(a, b, c) -> field1, List(x, y, z) -> field2)
```

I keep getting stuck on how I would map over `x` with `y` and return a `Map`.
Some direction would be greatly appreciated.

EDITED: This approach was inspired by this [talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rI8tNMsozo0) by Rich Hickey.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are on the right track with `zip`, you just need to be applying it to each item in `x` via `map` instead of applying it one time to `x` itself.  This is one solution, I'm sure there are others:

```
x.map(xs => y.zip(xs).toMap)
```

Comment: thanks this works, I'm still learning scala so I think I was missing something when I tried the map.